# How to go back to previous command when using monero cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I'm on ubuntu 14 and installed monero v0.11.1 - I'm trying to press the up arrow to go to my previous command, but that doesn't work. How can I get this to work? Also I sometimes want to clear the entire line with CTRL-L but that dosn't work either. I'm just looking to get bash commands to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If readline commands aren't working, there are two possibilities:

- you build without readline enabled (it's optional). Check libreadline-dev or equivalent package is installed (ie, the headers are usually missing when a basic package is installed on many distros)
- you have a bad ~/.inputrc - much less likely, but try moving it out of the way if you've really built with readline enabled.